# Error on embedding ruby source on c++ program

Tags: c++, ruby, qt, embedded-ruby

I'm not very experienced in C ++ yet but I'm trying to embed the ruby 1.8 in a qt application, and what I did until it was to download the ruby source code and put it in a project subfolder called '3rdparty' and run `./configure` inside that folder and after `make` and now I'm getting the followings errors:

> :-1: error: /home/gabriel/dev/ruby-exps/embed-ruby-first-tries/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374//libruby-static.a(dln.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO
>   missing from command line
>
> :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My .pro file is like this:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = embed-ruby-first-tries
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/release/ -lruby-static
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/debug/ -lruby-static
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/ -lruby-static

INCLUDEPATH += 3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374
DEPENDPATH += 3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/release/libruby-static.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/debug/libruby-static.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/release/ruby-static.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/debug/ruby-static.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/libruby-static.a
```

And my main.cpp file is like this:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <ruby.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ruby_init();

   return ruby_cleanup(0);
}
```

I'm using qt 5.6 and ruby 1.8.7-p374 source, it'll be great if anyone tell me how I do to embed the ruby on a cpp program or at least help me understand what's going on.

Comment: Add `-ldl` to linker arguments?

Comment: @Casper Do you mean add a line `LIBS += -ldl` on .pro file ? 
I'm not sure if was that but i did it and now it started to return this errors:
<br/>
**/home/gabriel/dev/ruby-exps/embed-ruby-first-tries/3rdparty/ruby-1.8.7-p374/string.c:4513: error: undefined reference to `crypt'**
<br/>
**:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: That I solved with `LIBS += -lcrypt`, thank you man, it's finally working, you should post this as the answer so I can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DSO missing from command line

This is usually a sign that you are missing some library from the linking phase. The error message is not very descriptive though.

In this case `undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose'` gives a hint of which library is missing. In this case `dlclose` happens to be in `libdl`. So adding:

```
-ldl
```

...to linker options (`LIBS +=`) should get you closer to the solution.